# CentOS, управление конфиг файлами через Git

Tags: linux, git, centos, config

Хочу организовать управление определёнными конфигами  и ресурсами в CentOS с помощью Git.

Мне нужны не все конфиги(как это делает etckeeper), а только содержимое например /etc/httpd, /etc/zabbix и содержимое каталога с вэб-сайтами /var/www в одном репозитории.
Вопрос: как лучше это организовать?

Если это важно, дистрибутив CentOS 7. Буду рад любой помощи.
Спасибо.

Comment: при помощи простенького bash или python скрипта, я полагаю

Comment: настрой `etckeeper` на то что тебе нужно... а `/var/www` я бы всё же держал в отдельной репе...